Is the angle between tangent vectors of a parametrized ruled surface constant along rulings despite singular points?

Definition. Let $M$ be a complete riemannian 3-manifold and $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ an open interval. Consider a smooth curve $p:I\to M$ and a unitary vector field $v:I\to TM$ along $p$. We define the ruled surface with base curve $p$ and directional curve $v$ as the image of map $\mathbf{X}:I\times \mathbb{R}\to M$ given by $\mathbf{X}(s,t) = \exp_{p(s)}(t v(s))$.

Of course $\mathbf{X}$ is not a immersion for any choiche of $p$ and $v$. However, we still don't want to ask $\mathbf{X}$ to be rigorously an immersion because there are some interesting surfaces which can't be represented as such and which we still would like to call "ruled surfaces" (for example, conic surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$).
On the other hand, we should state some regularity condition, in order to prevent the set to be completely degenerated.
Let's suppose for example that $\mathbf{X}$ is an immersion on a dense open subset of $I\times \mathbb{R}$.
Denote by $g$ the riemannian metric and $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita connexion on $M$.
I would like to do the following calculation around an immersion point:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} g(\mathbf{X}_s,\mathbf{X}_t) & = g(\nabla_{\mathbf{X}_t}\mathbf{X}_s,\mathbf{X}_t)+g(\mathbf{X}_s,\nabla_{\mathbf{X}_t}\mathbf{X}_t) \tag{compatibilty between $g$ and $\nabla$} \\
&= g(\nabla_{\mathbf{X}_t}\mathbf{X}_s,\mathbf{X}_t)\tag{$t\mapsto \mathbf{X}(s,t)$ is a geodesic}\\
&= g(\nabla_{\mathbf{X}_s}\mathbf{X}_t+[\mathbf{X}_t,\mathbf{X}_s],\mathbf{X}_t) \tag{symmetry between $\nabla$ and $[\,,\,]$}\\
&= g(\nabla_{\mathbf{X}_s}\mathbf{X}_t,\mathbf{X}_t) \tag{$[\mathbf{X}_t,\mathbf{X}_s]=0$ around an immersion point}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial s} g(\mathbf{X}_t,\mathbf{X}_t) \tag{compatibility again}\\
&= 0. \tag{$g(\mathbf{X}_t,\mathbf{X}_t)\equiv 1$}
\end{align*}

First question: Is this calculation correct? Can I really put $[\mathbf{X}_t,\mathbf{X}_s]=0$ around an immersion point even though $\mathbf{X}$ may have singular points elsewhere?


Second question: The function $g(\mathbf{X}_s,\mathbf{X}_t):I\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is well-defined and smooth despite singular points of $\mathbf{X}$. In particular, $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(\mathbf{X}_s,\mathbf{X}_t):I\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. So, if the calculation above is correct around immersion points, I would like to say that this partial derivative is identically zero for every point in $I\times \mathbb{R}$, even on singular ones, just by using continuity and the fact that the immersion points form an open dense subset of $I\times \mathbb{R}$. Is that thinking also correct?


Even if the inner product is constant, the angle is most definitely not.

@TedShifrin Ok, maybe I should use "inner product" instead of "angle" then haha. Anyways, what about the first and second questions? Do you think I may be missing something?

I would suggest that you start with $M=\Bbb R^3$ and investigate the most obvious examples of non-immersed ruled surfaces. For your first question, I don’t see what the issue is, as the Lie bracket of local coordinate vector fields is always $0$.

@TedShifrin I did that! Curiously, for $M=\mathbb{R}^3$ the thing works kind of trivially (even for a fully degenerated surface!). For we have $\mathbf{X}(s,t) = p(s)+tv(s)$, then $\partial_t \langle \mathbf{X}_s,\mathbf{X}_t\rangle = \partial_t \langle p'(s)+tv'(s), v(s)\rangle = \langle v'(s),v(s)\rangle =0$, since we're considering (without loss of generality when defining parametrized ruled surfaces) $|v|\equiv 1$. Again, we don't even need to ask any regularity condition on this, so this example is not really helpful (although it's interesting)
